# VBA POWERPOINT HTML Tag

Tags: vba, powerpoint

```
With slide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoShapeRectangle, 0, 0, 200.93, 109.286).TextFrame
Clipboard.GetFromClipboard

 .TextRange.PasteSpecial ppPasteHTML, msoFalse
End With
With slide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoShapeRectangle, 187.535, 190.929, 200.93, 109.286).TextFrame
Clipboard.GetFromClipboard

 .TextRange.PasteSpecial ppPasteHTML, msoFalse
End With
With slide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoShapeRectangle, 399.628, 19.9286, 200.93, 109.286).TextFrame
Clipboard.GetFromClipboard

 .TextRange.PasteSpecial ppPasteHTML, msoFalse
End With
```

I copied all the other HTML and put it on the clipboard.

However, the last copy of the clipboard will return the same value.

Is there a way to save the clipboard's saved HTML to a variable in the middle and return it as that value when the function is executed?